# Adding String Length Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding validation to my `text` string. It allows `string` and `integer` values, which is correct, but I want to require my `text` to be greater than 4 characters long. I've added the `text.Length > 4` but this does not add any validation when entering a **2** character string. Any suggestions?

```
public bool IsStringInvalid(string text)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                if (text != null && !Regex.IsMatch(text, textCodeFormat) && text.Length > 4)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I guess your first check should be `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))`,

Comment: Yep, I added that. Good suggestion, but still doesn't fix the string length validation.

Comment: Which is the value of textCodeFormat? and text!=null is redundant after String.isNullOrEmpty

Comment: @MarcCals `textCodeFormat = @"^(\d{5}?[-]?\d{4}|\d{5}|\d{5}-)$";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is called `IsStringLengthInvalid`, which implies that it should be returning true for invalid strings. Right now, it appears you're trying to return true only for valid strings.

Something like this should work:

```
    public bool IsStringInvalid(string text)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ||
            text.Length <= 4 ||
            !Regex.IsMatch(text, textCodeFormat);
    }
```

Comment: Good observation... I always look at what the code does but rarely at the function's name

Comment: @StriplingWarrior thanks for your help. This gets me closer, but This doesn't work if I enter a value like `fff444` Any ideas?

Comment: @CodeChaser: `"fff444"` doesn't match your regex. What is your regex intended to do?

Comment: @CodeChaser: Your `textCodeFormat` string will only match numbers, like you say in the OP. `"444444"` works just fine, but when you add letters in there, it makes the string invalid.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, when you mentioned `Regex` I realized that my regular expression was messing this up. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for not null condition nested inside the null condition which is logically wrong. You should do something like this.

```
public bool IsStringInvalid(string text)
        {

                if (text != null && text.Length > 4 && !Regex.IsMatch(text, textCodeFormat))
                {
                    return true;
                }

                    return false;

        }
```

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work. It still passes when entering two characters.

Answer (score 0):

You have your length validation if statement nested inside your other if. If text has any data if will never reach the nested if as it will fail the first since IsNullOrEmpty will return false.

I would do something like

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || !Regex.IsMatch(text, textCodeFormat) || text.Length < 4)
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: To fulfill the requirements: `Length <= 4`

Comment: @fcman, thanks for your reply, but this doesn't work if I pass something like `L7J1M7`